# SQL: Update registries generates Constraint violation

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, unique-constraint, ora-00001

I have a table like this:

[image: Table]

What i want to do is delete the first letter in Username column if this is an 'U'.

I have a problem if i do:

```
UPDATE table
     SET USERNAME= SUBSTR(USERNAME, 2, LENGTH(USERNAME))
     WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'U%';
```

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (SPE.UQ_P_USUARIO_NOMBRE) violated.

As you can see in the example, in the table exist the registry 1111-A, and when U1111-A is modifying the error appears.

I want to generate a query which modify just the registries that dont exist in the table.What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to update just the rows in which your update won't violate unique constraint you can use this

```
UPDATE `table`
SET USERNAME= SUBSTR(USERNAME, 2, LENGTH(USERNAME))
WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'U%'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `table` t WHERE t.USERNAME = SUBSTR(`table`.USERNAME, 2, LENGTH(`table`.USERNAME)) AND t.NAME = `table`.NAME);
```

This line checks if any rows with `username`-`name` pair you are trying to create already exist and if they do this row is not updated

```
NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `table` t WHERE t.USERNAME = SUBSTR(`table`.USERNAME, 2, LENGTH(`table`.USERNAME)) AND t.NAME = `table`.NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
    UPDATE table a
    SET USERNAME= SUBSTR(USERNAME, 2, LENGTH(USERNAME))
    WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'U%'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table b 
    where b.username=SUBSTR(a.USERNAME, 2, LENGTH(a.USERNAME)
    AND a.name=b.name)
```

Comment: Unique constraint in question is not on `username` but on `username` and `name`